# 'Either' propagation with IO()

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell, and having a great time. One of the things I especially enjoy is using the monad error types to propagate error conditions behind the scene in fmap or >>=. For example, in this code, I am using hoauth2 for an authenticated connection. It defines OAuth2Result using Either...

```
type OAuth2Result a = Either ByteString a  -- from OAuth2

getEntries :: Manager -> AccessToken -> IO(OAuth2Result [Entry])
  -- code omitted

filterResults :: [Entry] -> OAuth2Result [Entry]
filterResults = return $ filter hasUrl 

printEntries :: [Entry] -> IO()   -- What type can I use here?
printEntries Left l  =  -- code omitted
printEntries Right r =  -- code omitted

main = do
    entriesResult <- getEntries mgr token  -- This is an OAuth2Result
    let filtered = entriesResult >>= filterResults

    printEntries filtered
```

The problem that I am having is when a function has IO like printEntries. In this case, I have to explicitly pattern match to do the error handling. I would sure love to be able to hide it somehow as I did with the filterResults call.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: For `Either` there are lots of functions that do the pattern matching for you in `Data.Either`.  For example, [`rights`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=rights).  Is this sort of what you want?  How about `either print print`?

Comment: Also, you might want to check out [monad transformers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) (in particular [`ErrorT e IO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#v:ErrorT)).

Comment: Thanks. Monad transformers are exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just don't go nuts lifting functions and going in/out of transformers - that is sometimes a strong sign you haven't made a sufficient set of functions to support your level of abstraction.  In short - doing lots of lifting makes Peter a dull boy; pick a monad stack, make an API (sort of a DSL almost) and be content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it with `runEitherT` which requires some lifting and hoisting to get the types right:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Error

import Data.List (isInfixOf)

type Entry = String
type Result a = Either String a

sampleEntries = [ "good 1", "good 2", "good 3", "bad 4", "good 5", "bad 6", "good 7" ]

getEntries :: Int -> IO (Result [Entry])
getEntries n = if n >= 0 && n <= length sampleEntries
                 then return $ Right $ take n sampleEntries
                 else return $ Left $ "invalid n: " ++ show n

filterEntries :: [Entry] -> Result [Entry]
filterEntries ents = if all isGood ents
                       then Right $ ents
                       else Left "found a bad entry"
  where isGood str = isInfixOf "good" str

printEntries :: [Entry] -> IO ()
printEntries ents = forM_ (zip [1..] ents) $ \(i,e) -> print (i,e)

doit n = do
  ents <- (lift $ getEntries n) >>= hoistEither
  filtered <- hoistEither $ filterEntries ents
  lift $ printEntries filtered

main n = do result <- runEitherT $ doit n
            case result of
              Left e -> putStrLn $ "Error: " ++ e
              Right _ -> putStrLn $ "no errors"
```

Note the following behavior:

- `main 100` fails because `getEntries` returns an error
- `main 4` fails because `filterEntries` returns an error
- `main 3` succeeds